# Uploading 5kB image takes more than a minute and without success

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just tried to upload a 5kB GIF image to the question I'm composing but it is still saying 'Uploading ...' even after more than one minute!

Comment: This is of course a request for the team; my advice is to keep trying closing them, it will eventually work.

Comment: note that it works on meta.stats

Comment: I merged three questions that, although not identical, were just manifestations of the same problem and have exactly the same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to Adblock Plus Firefox plugin! When I disabled it for this particular site, the problem dissapeared!

Note that I hadn't this problem with Stack Overflow site, which is quite confusing so I didn't come to the idea it could be caused by Adblock Plus.

Comment: You have more reputation on SO, so you probably see no ads. On stats.SE with less reputation you are served ads and this is why you got the problem.